# Riemann Sum problems

Tags: c, algorithm, sum

I have two different programs, one is finding a Riemann Sum to a finite number using a for loop and that seems to be working just fine even though I had some stupid rounding errors I ended up finding.  The second program uses a while loop and prints the iterations until a specified value.  The first time the value pops up is at M=226 but when I run my while loop it shows at 227.  I can't understand why this is happening.

```
int main()
{
    int i=1,m=0;
    double x=0.0;
    printf ("the sum of i/(4i+2)^3 as i goes from one to M, please enter a M\n");
    scanf ("%d",&m);
    for(i;i<=m;i++)
    {
        x=x+(i/pow(4*i+2,3));
    }
    printf("the sum of your series is %.9lf\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    float x=0.0;
    while (x<0.011300)
    {
        x = x+((float)i/pow(4*i+2,3));
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is? is it in the for loop program or in the while?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `printf("after the loop is over, the i is equal to %d\n", i);` in your 1st example after the loop, you'd see it is equal to 227 at the end, not 226.

You make a wrong assumption that `i` must be equal to 226 at the end of execution. It **was** 226 when the loop condition was true the last time (i.e. `226 <= 226` being true), then your math calculations were performed and after that it got incremented, thus became 227. After that, on the next iteration the loop is over because `i <= m` isn't true anymore (the `i` is 227 at this moment).